# Error msg code with api of meaningcloud

Tags: c#, api

i try to use a categorized API from meaningcloud site for C# project, but i receive the 406 error. I even used the example that are published on their website with the same error, has anyone some experience with this API?

```
  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var client = new RestClient("http://api.meaningcloud.com/class-1.1");
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "key=MY_KEY_VALUE1b&txt=PRUEBA&model=IPTC_es", ParameterType.RequestBody);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        txtRespuesta.Text = response.Content;
    }
```

The msg error

```
<html><head>
<title>406 Not Acceptable</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Acceptable</h1>
<p>An appropriate representation of the requested resource /class-1.1 could not be found on this server.</p>
```

I wrote to them but I still don't have an answer, if someone has any idea of what I'm doing wrong please inform. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks heloisasim, I feel a little shame ..

Comment: Hi, the solution was: var client = new RestClient("http://api.meaningcloud.com/class-1.1.php");

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution:
var client = new RestClient("http://api.meaningcloud.com/class-1.1.php");